# Using QCompleter with strings composed by different words in QGIS Plugin - PyQT5

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qt, pyqt5

I'm using `QCompleter` in my QGIS plugin. The code below works well, but I'd love to make it more sophisticated. In this example I have some strings that are composed of some words, for example `"How to use QCompleter"`. In this moment, to see the completer I need to start writing by the first word ("How"). I'm wondering if there's a way to see the completer also writing in the LineEdit any word in the string, for example "to" or "use".

```
strList = ["Prove PyQt5", "How to use Qcompleter", "I love StackExchange"] 
completer = QCompleter()
completer.setCaseSensitivity(0)
dlg.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
model = QStringListModel()
model.setStringList(strList)
completer.setModel(model)
```

Comment: P.s. I know that the question is a bit off-topic, but I also know that here there are some people that are able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Qt.MatchContains` flag as filter mode.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter

completer = QCompleter()
completer.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
```

For further information: [Filter Modes for QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop).

Comment: Hi, many thanks once again. I always have trouble finding the right documentation for Qt.

Comment: I editted the link.  In previous link, just three of them are implemented for `QCompleter`.